# Plotly R: change hoverinfo font color according to different bar colors

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have this dataframe:

```
df2 = data.frame(value = c(9, 2, 7, 3, 6),
                 key = c('ar', 'or', 'br', 'gt', 'ko'))
```

And this is the code I have to generate [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZCg1.png)

```
df2 %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~key,
          y = ~value,
          type = 'bar',
          color = ~value,
          colors = c(rgb(0, 0, 0, 1), rgb(1, 0.85, 0.85, 1)),
          stroke = I('black'),
          span = I(1),
          hoverinfo = 'text',
          hovertext = ~paste0('value: ', value,
                              '\nkey: ', key)
          ) %>% 
  layout(hoverlabel = list(bordercolor = 'transparent', 
                           font = list(family = 'DM Sans', 
                                       size = 15, 
                                       color = 'white')))
```

But, as shown above, the `font color` of the `hoverinfo` is **white** when hovering over the lighter color.

Basically, I would like to set the font color to `black when the color is lighter`, and to `white when the color is dark`, as these images show: [black, when lighter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r4Kp.png), and [white, when darker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ3UA.png)

Any tips here?

Comment: Did you refer this? [https://plotly.com/r/hover-text-and-formatting/](https://plotly.com/r/hover-text-and-formatting/)

Comment: Not exactly... When the bar color is darker, I want the hoverinfo text to be white, at the same time that, when the bar color is lighter, the text should be black.
I know that this is possible when adding different traces to the plot, but is it possible without doing it? Like a dinamic way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an easier method than this, but this works. I've used the package `htmlwidgets`, in addition to `plotly`.

I've written in the change in text color as an event because the alternative is five separate traces like you eluded to in your question.

In the JS, I have an if–else statement where it queries the `pointerNumber`. The pointer number is the number of markers, bars, lines, whatever it is you have on your plot. In this case, it's bars.

The pointer numbers always start at zero and are consecutive numbers—don't assume the order matches the visualization. (I think it follows the order the data is provided, but I've never felt the need to investigate it, so I'm not 100% on that.)

In this code I changed pointer number 0 to have black text (that's the light pink one). If you felt that the `br` bar should also have black text, you could modify `if(pn === 0){` to `if(pn === 0 || pn === 2) {` and now the bar next to the pink one would also have black text. (Pointer number 1 happens to be the column on the far right.)

The event code:

```
hoverer = "function(el, x) {
            el.on('plotly_hover', function(d){
              var pn = d.points[0].pointNumber;
              var fon = [];
              var hov = [];
              if(pn === 0){ 
                col = 'black';
              } else {
                col = 'white'};
              fon = {
                'family': 'DM Sans',
                'size': 15,
                'color': col};
              hov = {
                'bordercolor': 'transparent',
                'font': fon};
              h = {hoverlabel: hov};
              Plotly.restyle(el.id, h);
            });}"
```

This is how you use it with your graph:

```
df2 %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~key,
          y = ~value,
          type = 'bar',
          color = ~value,
          colors = c(rgb(0, 0, 0, 1), rgb(1, 0.85, 0.85, 1)),
          stroke = I('black'),
          span = I(1),
          hoverinfo = 'text',
          hovertext = ~paste0('value: ', value,
                              '\nkey: ', key)) %>% 
  layout(hoverlabel = list(bordercolor = 'transparent', 
                           font = list(family = 'DM Sans', 
                                       size = 15, 
                                       color = 'white'))) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(hoverer) # this will trigger the event driven code
```

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: hey, I know you posted this a while back but how would I modify this if I had several lines in a line chart and I wanted some of the hovertexts to be white, some black? The code that you provided doesn't work because it doesn't colour the hovertext for the different lines, it colours the ones for the markers if that makes sense.

Comment: I think I would need to know more about the data and plot structure you're working with. It might be easiest for you to ask your question to the forum ([a reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)). You could even refer to this answer in your question. It's pretty likely you'd get some great answers quickly. If you wanted, you could even add a comment here with a link to the question. If you're dev tools savvy, you can use `el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) { console.log('Hover: ', d); });` to see what Plotly gives you to work with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76098448/plotly-r-change-hoverinfo-font-color-depending-on-different-lines-in-line-chart I'll leave this related question here for now :) Thank you!