# Plotly R: Change hoverinfo font color depending on different lines in line chart

Tags: r, graph, fonts, plotly

I want to change the hoverinfo font color for some of my line chart lines but not for all of them.

Here's some code that's similiar to mine:

```
number <- rep(c(00, 01, 02), each = 4)
animal <- rep(c("cat", "dog", "mouse"), each = 4)
year <- rep(c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013), time = 3)
value <-  c(4, 3, 12,
            8, 19, 2,
            10, 11, 9)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(number, animal, year, value))

chosen_colors <- c("#e7ca60",
            "#5778a4",
            "#a87c9f"
                     )

fig <-
  df %>% 
  plot_ly(.,
          y=~value,
          x = ~year,
          color = ~number,
          name = ~animal,
          colors = ~chosen_colors,
          type = 'scatter',
          mode = 'lines+markers',
          hovermode = "closest",
          hovertemplate = paste0("<b>", df$animal,"</b><br>",
                                 "<i>Year</i>: ", df$year ,"<br><extra></extra>",
                                 "<i>Value</i>: ",
                                 df$value," €<br>"))
fig <-
  fig %>% 
  layout(title = "<b>Testing (2010–2013)</b>",
         titlefont = list(size = 20),
         font = list(family = "calibri",size = 16),
         separators = ',.',
         yaxis = list(title = "Value"),
         xaxis = list(title = list(text = "", standoff = 3),
                      zeroline = FALSE),
         legend = list(orientation = 'v'))
fig
```

So basically, in this example, I would want the hoverinfo font color for the animal "mouse" to be white instead of the blackish grey that R chooses for me.
The font color for the cat is perfect. The one for the dog too!
I would like to do this as simply as possible, maybe with a condition on either the animal name or the number (not the row number but the column that's called number in this df) or even the hexcode.

Here's a similiar question but it's about a barchart. I wasn't able to change the code to fit my problem:
[Plotly R: change hoverinfo font color according to different bar colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974573/plotly-r-change-hoverinfo-font-color-according-to-different-bar-colors/72072669#comment134062540_72072669)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you needed here was `curveNumber`, which is typically based on the number of traces (usually equivalent to the number of colors in your plot, if discretely colored).

Since you only want one trace to change, you can add the `curveNumber` to the final call in the JS, `Plotly.restyle(el.id, h, 2);`.

So how did I know that the 'mouse' trace was the number 2? Again, *typically* this can be quickly determined by looking at your legend, where indexing starts at zero. So in this plot cat = 0, dog = 1, and mouse = 2.

Here's the code:

```
hover2 =  "function(el, x) {
            el.on('plotly_hover', function(d){
              h = {hoverlabel: {'font': {'color': 'white'}}};
              Plotly.restyle(el.id, h, 2); /*currently cat: 0, dog: 1, mouse: 2 */
            });}"

fig %>% htmlwidgets::onRender(hover2)
```

[image]

(BTW: in your question's `hovertemplate`, you wrote `df$years`, but it should be `df$year`)

Comment: Thank you very much! That works like a charm. I also edited my mistake in my post :) Thanks for telling me!